Facing "Linked AMP version is not available to Google" Error in AMP Page Test
I have a website but there are a few errors inside the AMP tab in the Google Search Console. When we test the homepage in the AMP test, it says "Linked AMP version is not available to Google".
I have no AMP application installed on Shopify. The homepage website is automatically redirecting to this URL /a/amp-sb/home and it is showing a 404 not found error. The theme on the website is NEW Site Refresh.
Here is the screenshot of the URL and the AMP test report: https://imgur.com/a/CKehr6K
Now I want to remove the redirect from the homepage to /a/amp-sb/home and use the normal version of the homepage as the amp.
Please someone help me.
I tried to install an AMP app on Shopify but it is still not solved.
